# How to improve wordpress postmeta based select query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-database

I have created a function which get me post_id from postmeta table using meta value. Before this i was using inbuilt function from Learndash and using that my database query time was around 3.2 seconds. But after writing my own function i was able to reduce it by .4 seconds. But i still think it can be optimized more because **Query Monitor** plugin is marking my query also as slow.

screenshot:

[image: Query Monitor Slow queries]

I am trying to improve the speed of below code and I have tried all of possible workaround and techniques.

This is the code:

```
public function ntml_question_pid_by_proid($meta_value)
        {
            global $wpdb;

            $tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

            $prepare_guery = $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT post_id 
  FROM $tbl 
 where meta_key = 'question_pro_id' 
   and meta_value like '%s'
", $meta_value);

            $get_values = $wpdb->get_col($prepare_guery);

            if (is_array($get_values) && count($get_values) > 0) {
                return $get_values[0];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Is there a workaround that will improve page speed by minimum of 2 seconds?

We already have memcache too.

Comment: you can add indexing to meta_value column

Comment: @ParthShah what could be the worst effect of adding index on meta_value. In general meta_value can have any type of data in it. For example: String, Number, Json or anything... Here is [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292831/add-indexing-to-meta-value-in-wp-postmeta) to another stackoverflow post which shows after adding index made query so slow..

Comment: postmeta is poorly indexed.  See this for advice: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 0):

Stale question, I know.

Try adding columns to postmeta's meta_key index index.

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta 
  DROP INDEX meta_key,
  ADD INDEX (meta_key(32), meta_value(32), post_id);
```

Or use the [WP Index MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) plugin. It updates quite a few indexes.